# How do I make a form change text in a different PHP/HTML file?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a "banner.php" thing that's included in every single page of my site so I can have alerts about when site maintenance is, etc.
So my question is,
How do I make a form change text in a different HTML file?

As in: Make a page (admin.php) or some page like that have a form with a button. Whenever I change the form and hit the button, it makes banner.php's text change.

I know it would involve a variable in the banner.php file, but I'm not sure how to execute a line of code that would change said file from a different file.

Comment: just create variable, then include banner and in the banner file check  that variables value. IT IS that simple :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, the simplest would probably be to store your new content in a file.

Something along these lines:

`admin.php`:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
New value: <input type="text" name="new_text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

`save.php`:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('banner_content.txt', $_POST['new_text']);
```

`banner.php`:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('banner_content.txt');
```

This is extremely basic, and I would definetely not recommend that you use it as is - it has no security measures whatsoever, and is probably not very useful on it's own either... but it's a starting point if you are completely blank.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using a user system that disallows users that don't have administrator privileges and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the banner file
`$banner=file_get_contents("banner.php");`

so after doing the changes in a form or wherever you can save your data in the file and overwrite it:

```
file_put_contents("banner.php",$banner);
```